# MySQL Weird Date Error (Incorrect datetime value)

Tags: mysql, datetime

I can't really explain what's happening here. Here are three MySQL queries wherein they only differ in the YEAR. One is not working!

Query 1: (OK)

```
update `users` set `updated_at` = '2018-03-10 02:14:26' where `id` = 7
```

Query 2: (OK)

```
update `users` set `updated_at` = '2020-03-10 02:14:26' where `id` = 7
```

Query 3: (MySQL Error Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-10 02:14:26')

```
update `users` set `updated_at` = '2019-03-10 02:14:26' where `id` = 7
```

What's going on here? This is obviously a valid date which is today, March 10, 2019.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your problem](https://rextester.com/HAE75979), and I suspect a simple typo somewhere.  Make your problem reproducible if you want to get help here.

Comment: Hi Tim. But the only difference between those queries is one character.

Comment: I created another table with the same structure. The third query is okay. I wonder what's going on.

Comment: As I mentioned in the above comment, most likely you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I did not make this query. This query was made by laravel to update the updated_at field. This date is definitely made by their Carbon library.

Comment: Hi Travis, do you have two SO accounts?

Comment: Is it related to daylight saving? It started at around same time.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on MySQL 5.7.24 but that is super suspicious as to the DST thing. Are you on a current version of MySQL?

Comment: I may have found an explanation/solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55084791/6038111

Comment: Hi Travis... yes thanks that's for sure the reason explained in that post...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel SQLSTATE\[22007\]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2019-03-10 02:00:39' for column 'updated\_at' (daylight savings?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084109/laravel-sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1292-incorrect-datetime-value)

Comment: Hello, as what @fiberair mentioned above, yes, it is somewhat related to DST. Thanks for all the help. Also, this question is 3 years old in which daylight savings time will not matter as it has been abolished. :)